# how to set parameters to app.config file

Tags: c#

1. I want to set some parameters to my own App.Config file programmatically?

I tried the following code  for 1 question but it is not working.

```
Configuration config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("param1", "value1");

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

My second questions is

Can I access & update App.Config file of other Project if yes how to do that?
plz guide me.

Comment: Friend, you're going to have to work a little bit harder on this question. I want you to think about it from our perspective. We don't know what's ***not working***. Further, you can always access a configuration file at runtime, but the question is this, are you asking us if you can access it the same way you're accessing the other one (i.e. like in the above code example) or are you literally just asking us to write that code for you?

Answer (score 0):

this code perfectly work for me. Take a look at the Debug or Release folder of your application and see the yourProjectName.Exe.Config file. The Application.ExecutablePath is one of this.